# React Infinite Scroll with qwest

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, xmlhttprequest, create-react-app

I'm currently trying to build a webapp with `create-react-app` and the packages `Infinite-Scroller` and `qwest`

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-infinite-scroller)

(https://www.npmjs.com/package/qwest)

my code currently looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Table from '@material-ui/core/Table';
import TableHead from '@material-ui/core/TableHead';
import TableBody from '@material-ui/core/TableBody';
import TableCell from '@material-ui/core/TableCell';
import TableRow from '@material-ui/core/TableRow';
import TableSortLabel from '@material-ui/core/TableSortLabel';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import { darken } from '@material-ui/core/styles/colorManipulator';
import InfiniteScroll from 'react-infinite-scroller';
import qwest from 'qwest';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/database';

class ShowTable extends Component {

    constructor(props) { // While load / default data
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            listingData: [],
            hasMoreItems: true
        };
    }

    loadItems(page) {
        let dbUrl = 'https://example.firebaseio.com/users.json?limitToLast=1&orderBy="$key"';
        // Variables for InfiniteScrollitems
        let ending = 9390; // Should be updated with get-function below... 
        qwest.get(dbUrl)
            .then(function(xhr, response) {
                let result;
                result = Object.keys(response)[0];
                result = Math.ceil(result / 5) * 5;
                ending = result;
            });

        let that = this;
        let urlDB = 'https://example.firebaseio.com/users.json';
        let startAt = 0;
        let endAt = 5;
        qwest.get(urlDB, {
                orderBy: '"$key"',
                startAt: '"' + startAt + '"',
                endAt: '"' + endAt + '"'
            })
            .then(function(xhr, response) {
                console.log("response is here");
                if (endAt <= ending) {
                    let listingData = that.state.listingData;
                    console.log("i came through if endAt/ending");
                    response.map((dataList) => {
                        listingData.push(dataList);
                    });
                    console.log(listingData);
                    that.setState({
                        listingData: listingData
                    });
                    console.log("i came after setState listingData");
                } else {
                    console.log("i came through else");
                    that.setState({
                        hasMoreItems: false
                    });
                }
                startAt = startAt + 5;
                endAt = endAt + 5;
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { spacing } = this.state;
        const { classes } = this.props;

        const loader = <tr><td><div className="loader">Loading...</div></td></tr>;
        let items = [];
        this.state.listingData.map((tableData, i) => {
            console.log("Test");
            let listA;
            let listB;
            if (tableData.fromListA === "1" && tableData.fromListB === "1") {
                listA = "x";
                listB = "x";
            } else if (tableData.fromListA === "1") {
                listA = "x";
            } else if (tableData.fromListB === "1") {
                listB = "x";
            }
            items.push( 
                <TableRow key={i} data-key={i}>
                 <TableCell>{tableData.userid}</TableCell> 
                 <TableCell>{tableData.username}</TableCell> 
                 <TableCell>{listA}</TableCell> 
                 <TableCell>{listB}</TableCell> 
                 <TableCell>{tableData.lastChecked}</TableCell> 
                </TableRow>
            );
        });

        return ( 
            <Table className={classes.table} id="dataTable">
             <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
               <TableCell>userid</TableCell> 
               <TableCell>username</TableCell> 
               <TableCell>on listA</TableCell> 
               <TableCell>on listB</TableCell> 
               <TableCell>Handle updated</TableCell> 
              </TableRow> 
             </TableHead>

            <InfiniteScroll 
              pageStart={0}
              loadMore={this.loadItems.bind(this)}
              hasMore={this.state.hasMoreItems}
              loader={loader}
              element={'tbody'}
              className={classes.root}
              initialLoad={true}
              useWindow={true} 
             >
              {items} 
            </InfiniteScroll>

           </Table>
        )
    }
}
```

my 2 problems are the following:

1: I can't update `let ending` with the qwest.get value I get, I don't know how to do that.

2: I come through the if condition where it says `console.log("i came through if endAt/ending")` but after that, the script simply doesn't do anything anymore. no console log whatsoever, no items in `listingData` or anything, and I don't know why. I get one error about keys on the `<InfiniteScroll>` Element, but it should at least render, but it doesn't. and i can't figure out why.

I'm new to react and still learning so... I'm sorry if it's like a really "dumb" mistake i make here, but I'm actually clueless for 2 days now.

//Edit:

This is my console

[image: Error Console]

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts

1. I think this is happening because of the nature of the async calls.  You're doing your initial `qwest.get` async, then set some variables and call the second `qwest.get` before the first one could get the data.  If you need the call to be sync'd I'd throw everything after the first `qwest.get` into it's own function and then call it within the then statement in the first `qwest.get`.  Something like....

```
qwest.get(dbUrl)
   .then(function(xhr, response) {
      let result = Object.keys(response)[0];
      result = Math.ceil(result / 5) * 5;
      this.continueLoad(result, page)
});
```

2. There's a few issues I'm seeing

   - No need for `let that = this`, just use `this`
   - You aren't using `page` anywhere, I think you want to do the following and remove the logic to reset the startAt/endAt variables at the end since they aren't doing anything.

```
let startAt = 0 + (page - 1) * 5
let endAt = 5 + (page - 1) * 5
```

- Change your `response.map` to a `forEach` and add some logging to ensure the response and rows are the format you expect.  My guess is that the response is not the correct format (in your first `qwest.get` you use `Object.keys(response)` before getting data).

```
console.log("i came through if endAt/ending")
console.log(response)
response.forEach((dataList) => {
   console.log(dataList)
   listingData.push(dataList)
})
```

Comment: i tried using the demo from infinite scroller at https://github.com/CassetteRocks/react-infinite-scroller/blob/master/docs/src/index.js

Comment: Your code is different though. Two qwest calls instead of one; get call has different parameters; mapping is different.... I’d recommend starting with that example and just swap out the DB url to start

Comment: yeah but i need the first one, to get the last item in my database - to know how many items are there.

Comment: Get it to work first w/out that call.  You could get around it by assuming there are records left and only if no data is returned do you flip the flag.  It shouldn't be something that gets in your way to get it up and running, regardless.  Keep it as simple as possible to begin and then make small changes to get it where you want.

Comment: btw, the first return of the last ID from the database is correct, i checked that already. it's just doesn't save the value in the variable. and i don't know why.

Comment: if i `console.log(dataList)` it doesn't show up. but the response does before the forEach shows up as an Object.

Comment: whats in the response object?

Comment: a key, and the data i requested - one key per dataset. if i convert it into an Array the forEach works, but i now get the error that i can't use `setState` or `this.state.listingData` because it's not binded... how do i bind something? and to what?

Comment: `this.loadItems.bind(this)` should handle the binding according to the docs.  You should be able to get rid of it by updating loadItems to a function like `loadItems = page =>` and then update `loadMore={this.loadItems.bind(this)}` to `loadMore={this.loadItems}`

Comment: `this.loadItems.bind(this)` doesn't work in `<InfiniteScroller>`. it gets struck when i set the variable to `this.state.listingData` OR (if i'm putting an empty array there) at `this.setState`. with the same error.